# в supervisor старые данные из базы

Tags: mysql, laravel, очередь, supervisord

воркер работает в бесконечном цикле и получает задачи из очереди. Почему supervisor  работает с устаревшими данными из базы? Модели со старыми данными.

```
`$worker = new Worker();

$class = new ApiaryController();

do {

    $job = $worker->cache()->lpop('jobs:buy_cells');

    if ($job) {
        $job = json_decode($job);

        switch ($job->method)
        {
            case 'cell':
                $result = $class->cell($job);
                break;
            case 'honeycomb':
                $class->honeycomb($job);
                break;
        }

        if(!empty($result) && isset($job->guid)) {
            $worker->cache()->setex('jobs:' . $job->guid, 3600, json_encode($result));
        }
    }
} while ($exit_metka);`
```

мой кусок кода с бесконечным циклом

Comment: А при чём тут supervisord? Если его не использовать, то данные нормальные?

Comment: обрабатываю задачи в одном потоке одним воркером. для этого использую supervisor

Comment: Рад за вас, но на вопрос не ответили. Какое отношение к описанной проблеме имеет supervisor? Если его не использовать, то данные нормальные?

Comment: у меня выполняется скрипт с  бесконечным циклом. скрипт запускаю супервизором с одним воркером.  выполняю какую либо задачу например покупку в тот момент когда недостаточно баланса. получаю уведомление что недостаточно баланса. пополняю. и опять недостаточно баланса. смотрю в логи. данные не изменились. тоесть не отобразился новый баланс из базы. после рестарта супервизора всё норм. опыта с ним имею не так много. поэтому подозреваю, что может быть как и со скриптом. пока не рестартнешь изменения не примутся

Comment: И снова на вопрос не ответили. Если supervisor **не использовать**, то данные нормальные?

Comment: Если запустить воркер без использования супервизора `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: данные нормальные. до использования супервизора данные были нормальные